# What is $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^ne^{−x^2}?$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^ne^{−x^2}?$$ for any $n$ I think its $0$ because the exponential will go faster to $0$ than the nth power go to +∞, but I don't see which theorem to apply to reach the result.

Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: From the power series for $e^x,$ you get $$e^{x^2}>\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Follows from $lim_{x\to \infty} \ln(x)/x = 0$.

Comment: Note that $\ln x^ne^{-x^2} = n\ln x - x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider also this amusing way to see it:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^n e^{-x^2} = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{e^{x^2}}$$

We can use De L'Hôpital rule here. Clearly using it once won't give you any immediate result (if we don't take into account hierarchy orders of rapidity and so on). Indeed after using H once:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{e^{x^2}} \longrightarrow \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{n x^{n-1}}{2x e^{x^2}}$$

The interesting part is mentally use it $n$ times, where you can easily perceive by intuition that

$$\dfrac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n} x^n = n!$$

as well as

$$\dfrac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n} e^{x^2} = c(n) e^{x^2} P^n(x)$$

where $P^n(x)$ represents a polynomial of degree $n$ and $c(n)$ is a constant depending on $n$ only.

Whence:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^n e^{-x^2} = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{n!}{c(n) e^{x^2} P^n(x)} \to 0$$

Comment: Very good explanation.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you! I just thought it could be likeable to show this :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We have $${x^n\over e^{x^2}}=\left ( {x\over e^{x^2/n}}\right )^n$$ Therefore it suffices to show that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} {x\over e^{x^2/n}}=0$$ We can use $e^t\ge t,$  for $t\ge 0$, i.e. $e^{x^2/n}\ge x^2/n.$ Hence $$0\le {x\over e^{x^2/n}}\le {n\over x}$$